# Prevent authenticated users to access custom sign in page with next-auth middleware

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, middleware, next-auth

we are currently developing an application with NextJS 13 using `next-auth`, so far everything is great. Our application uses a custom sign-in page with a `CredentialsProvider` and we protect our routes using the next-auth middleware. We would like to prevent our users from accessing `/login` if they are already authenticated. We managed to achieve this in the client with  `useSession()` but we are looking for a way to have this logic in the middleware instead. Is this possible to achieve with the current `next-auth` middleware implementation? Below is our current middleware and route configurations. Thank you.

```
//middleware.ts
import withAuth from 'next-auth/middleware';

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: `/login`,
  },
});
```

and

```
//route.ts
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

const handler = NextAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: `/login`,
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: 'Username', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        //auth logic here
      },
    }),
  ],
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Comment: Couldn't you do it in the `getServerSideProps` on the login page?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar yes, we currently use the `app` folder but we could make something equivalent to`getServerSideProps` in there. However middleware runs on the edge so I think we could achieve better performance, also we would have all the route redirection logic in a single place, but doing it like you suggest would definitely work.

Comment: I see the point @alexortizl, and yeah it would make sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is working for us. Also credits to @Yilmaz, this is based on his answer.

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const isAuthenticated = !!token;

  if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/login') && isAuthenticated) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', req.url));
  }

  const authMiddleware = await withAuth({
    pages: {
      signIn: `/login`,
    },
  });

  // @ts-expect-error
  return authMiddleware(req, event);
}
```

Comment: Why did you call getToken api instead of getServerSession api?

Comment: @JonasBeck `getServerSession` won't work in the middleware. If you would like more details, check this [issue](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7732).

Comment: @Shabbir Ahmad, what if user will be using browser's buttons (back/forward)? Middleware will not trigger, because of client cache, which you cannot optout. Am i wrong?

Answer (score 7):

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// For the time being, the withAuth middleware only supports "jwt" as session strategy.
export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(req) {
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    // if token exists, !!token will be true
    const isAuthenticated = !!token;
   
    // first, check if the current path is login page
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
      // I am in "login" page now  I check if the user is authenticated or not
      if (isAuthenticated) {
         // If I get here it means user is on "login" page and it is authenticated. then redirect it to whatever url
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/whatever", req.url));
      }
     
    }
);

// specify on which routes you want to run the middleware
export const config = {
  matcher: ["/", "/login""],
};
```

Comment: Thank you @Yilmaz, your answer was crucial for me to figure this out.  In your answer it seems that `witAuth` won't call the `middleware`  function if the route is `/login` so it will never get to the redirection logic. What I did was basically to create a middleware with that redirection logic and nest the `withAuth` middleware inside of it. I will post it into an answer so other people can benefit.

Comment: @alexortizl you had to add match array

Comment: I tried with match array but still no calls to `middleware`.  My guess is that the logic inside `withAuth` skips any route that is set in `pages.signIn`, for example `{pages: {signIn: '/login'}}`

Comment: not true. did u export the config as above

Comment: yes, copy/paste from your snippet and added `{pages: {signIn: '/login'}}` after `middleware` in `withAuth`.

Comment: @alexortizl is correct. The evidence can be found [here](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/93f9153d7758a90dd9566a29f3c7b2381f0caf00/packages/next-auth/src/next/middleware.ts#L113).

Answer (score 0):

Using Next@13.5.6 and next-auth@4.24.3 the solution by @alexortizl still works.

Here is a simplified js version of it.

```
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';
import { withAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export default async function middleware(req) {
     const token = await getToken({ req });
     const isAuthenticated = !!token;

     if (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/auth/signin') && isAuthenticated) {
          return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/protected/profile', req.url));
     }

     return await withAuth(req, {
          pages: {
               signIn: '/auth/signin',
          },
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @alexortizl but expanded in use-case if it's helpful to anyone

```
export default async function middleware(req, event) {
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    const isAuthenticated = !!token;

    // if the user is already authenticated and tries to access one of the auth pages
    // redirect to the home page
    if (
        (req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") ||
            req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/sign-up") ||
            req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/forgot-password")) &&
        isAuthenticated
    ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/", req.url));
    }

    // if the user is not authenticated, allow them to visit the auth pages
    if (
        req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/welcome") ||
        req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login") ||
        req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/sign-up") ||
        req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/forgot-password")
    ) {
        return fetch(req);
    }

    // if the user is not authenticated and tries to access any other page
    // redirect to the login page
    const authMiddleware = withAuth({
        pages: {
            signIn: `/login`
        }
    });

    return authMiddleware(req, event);
}

// config to match all pages
export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|.*\\.png$).*)"]
};
```