# NextJS redirect from login to dashboard if authenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

With this example, I can have nextjs redirect to a given page like the login if someone isn't authenticated. However, I can I modify this so that if a user is authenticated and the page is something like the login, redirect them to the dashboard or something? Is there a config for that? Like `matcher` will maintain the private URLs just fine. But In the case of specific public ones I don't want users to access will logged in how do I resolve that with something like this? Is that possible?

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
  const token = req.headers.get('token') // TODO: get token from request header
  const userIsAuthenticated = false // TODO: check if user is authenticated
  console.log('middleware.ts', 'token', token);
  if (!userIsAuthenticated) {
    const signinUrl = new URL('/login', req.url)
    return NextResponse.redirect(signinUrl)
  }

  

  return NextResponse.next()
}

// Here you can specify all the paths for which this middleware function should run
// Supports both a single string value or an array of matchers
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/api/auth/:path*', '/'],
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent authenticated users to access custom sign in page with next-auth middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175812/prevent-authenticated-users-to-access-custom-sign-in-page-with-next-auth-middlew)

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work, just create a file named `middleware.ts` in the root directory of your project. It will check if the session has a valid jwt token, and if it doesn't, it will redirect to a desired page.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';
import { getToken } from 'next-auth/jwt';

const secret = process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET;

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
    const session = await getToken({ req, secret });
    const { pathname } = req.nextUrl;

    if (session && (pathname === '/login' || pathname === '/register')) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', req.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Next-Auth for authentication:

Wrap the middleware with `withAuth` and use the token variable provided by Next-Auth to validate session, then redirect to the `route` of your will according to the session validity.

Here is a TS code that might help:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { withAuth, NextRequestWithAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware';

export default withAuth(function middleware (request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
    const session = request?.nextauth?.token;

    if (request.nextUrl.pathname === '/') return NextResponse.next();
    if (!session && request.nextUrl.pathname !== '/login') 
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
    if (session && request.nextUrl.pathname !== '/dashboard')
        return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', request.url));

    return NextResponse.next();
},
{
    callbacks: {
        authorized: () => true,
    },
});

export const config = {
    matcher: [
        '/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico).*)',
    ],
};
```