# Next auth middleware custom route protection

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I know this is a duplicate of [Prevent authenticated users to access custom sign in page with next-auth middleware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175812/prevent-authenticated-users-to-access-custom-sign-in-page-with-next-auth-middlew), however both answers provided do not work. The browser get stuck in an infinte loader. I am also using the latest Next.js and next auth version.

I am trying to protect the routes :

- `/dashboard` `/exercises/*` - Those two routes should only be accessible by signed in users
- `/` `/sign-in` `/verify-request` - Those three routes should only be accessible by not signed in users

Current middlware:

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";

export const config = { matcher: ["/dashboard/:path*", "/exercises/:path*"] };
```

From the link above I have tried the following:

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextFetchEvent, NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(
  req: NextRequest,
  event: NextFetchEvent
) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const isAuthenticated = !!token;
  const url = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  if (
    (url.startsWith("/sign-in") || url === "/verify-request" || url === "/") &&
    isAuthenticated
  ) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
  }

  const authMiddleware = withAuth({
    pages: {
      signIn: `/sign-in`,
    },
  });

  // @ts-expect-error
  return authMiddleware(req, event);
}
```

and

```
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default withAuth(async function middleware(req) {
  const token = await getToken({ req });
  const isAuthenticated = !!token;
  const url = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  console.log(url);

  if (
    url === "/" ||
    url === "/sign-in" ||
    url === "/verify-request" ||
    url.startsWith("/dashboard") ||
    url.startsWith("/exercises")
  ) {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/dashboard", req.url));
    }

    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/sign-in", req.url));
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/",
    "/sign-in",
    "/verify-request",
    "/dashboard/:path*",
    "/exercises/:path*",
  ],
};
```