# Why my next auth and middleware config still make user can go to login page after user has logged in?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, middleware

Why after I logged in it still can go to the /api/auth/signin which is my login page?
It's like my middleware doesnt trigger on my login page?
Also please check whether this is the right way to create next auth and middleware config?

this is my api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```
const handler = NextAuth({
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Sign in",
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { username, password } = credentials as Credentials;

        const { data } = await api.post("/cms/auth/login", {
          username,
          password,
        });

        const user = {
          id: Math.random().toString(),
          role: data.data.role,
          token: data.data.token,
        };

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token }: { session: any; token: any }) {
      session.user = token.user;
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

this is my ./middleware.ts

```
export default withAuth(
  async function middleware(request) {
    const { token } = request.nextauth;
    console.log('on middleware')

    if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/api/auth/login", request.url));
    }

    const { user } = token;

    if (user.role === "PARTNER") {
      if (request.url.includes("/cms/admin") || request.url.includes("/api/auth")) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          new URL("/cms/partner/dashboard", request.url),
        );
      }
    } else if (user.role === "ADMIN") {
      if (
        request.url.includes("/cms/partner") ||
        request.url.includes("/auth")
      ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          new URL("/cms/admin/dashboard", request.url),
        );
      }
    }
  },
  {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  }
);
```

After I logged in, user still can go to login page (/api/auth/signin).
It's like my middleware doesnt trigger on login page.
Even the console log 'on middleware' doesnt trigger when user at /api/auth/signin

Comment: that would suggest `(!token)` is true?

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean? Even the first console log doenst trigger when on sign in page

Comment: I just read your title, and saw the code `if (!token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/api/auth/login", request.url));
    }` which would suggest  you redirect if `!token` is true

Comment: Sorry, I just edited, user still can go to login page when already logged in, that's what I asked.

Comment: Oh, so the user can go to the login page when logged in ... right, so which part of your code attempts to prevent them from reaching the login page if they are already logged in?

Comment: if (user.role === "PARTNER") {
      if (request.url.includes("/cms/admin") || request.url.includes("/api/auth")) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          new URL("/cms/partner/dashboard", request.url),
        );
      }
    } else if (user.role === "ADMIN") {
      if (
        request.url.includes("/cms/partner") ||
        request.url.includes("/auth")
      ) {
        return NextResponse.redirect(
          new URL("/cms/admin/dashboard", request.url),
        );
      }
    }

this, if they are already has role, and trying to go to login page, should redirect

Comment: which ones the login page that you don't want them to visit when logged in? i.e. what is the value of `request.url` that you want to redirect for

Comment: Before that, I just want you to know that my middleware doesn't trigger when I'm on /api/auth/signin (which is my login page), look at the console log console.log('on middleware'), it's triggered when im on any other page beside login page.

Comment: Have you chekced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175812/prevent-authenticated-users-to-access-custom-sign-in-page-with-next-auth-middlew?

Comment: @YoussoufOumar, I did changed everything to that, but it's still can go to login page.